# Rearranging an equation to have only one variable on the LHS

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

All, I am very new to Mathematica, but through searching have not found a solution to this problem.

Is it possible now to rearrange an equation to have only one variable on the left hand side?

I have the following equation and I would like to solve for theta double dot:

r[t] = h Sec[[Theta][t]] ((Sec[[Theta][t]]^2 + Tan[[Theta][t]]^2) Derivative[1][[Theta]][t]^2 + Tan[[Theta][t]] ([Theta]^[Prime][Prime])[t])

basically I a position function r[t_]:= h Sec[theta[t]] and I am taking the second derivative of it with respect to time and then solving for theta double dot on one side.

Is it possible to get mathematica to rearrange the equation for me?

Comment: `Replace[Solve[eqn, var], {{a_ -> b_}} :> a == b]` maybe. -- You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful. It would encourage others to answer if you could post a properly formatted equation you want rearranged.

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212598/isolating-a-specific-variable-to-one-side-in-an-equation

Comment: Michael's comment worked for me...sorry for the messy copy of the eqn, will try and fix this next time